# Yet another ClickOnce GAC reference question

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am trying to deploy an update and all of a sudden I am getting the message about log4net.dll version 1.2.10.0 needing to be installed in the GAC.  This is version number 38 and I have property set to Copy Local = true, and set the value to Include on the Application Files setting.  I even gave up and registered the log4net.dll into the GAC on the target machine.  Funny thing is this update rolls out just fine on two other computers.

I am not sure what might have changed since the last update?

cheers

bob

edit: I found this entry in the manifest file for log4net.  It is not in any of the other manifest files for other applications where I use log4net?  Yet if I try to modify the file, clickonce knows and says the install is corrupted.

```
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite" allowDelayedBinding="true">
  <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" version="1.2.10.0" publicKeyToken="692FBEA5521E1304" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: was log4net registered in gac on these other computers?

Comment: Random thing - change "Copy Local" to false and then back to true - does that fix it? I'll explain more if it works :)

Comment: No log4net was not in the GAC on the other computers.  It was a stupid Hail Mary effort on my part to solve the issue on the one computer.

Comment: Changed the Copy Local to false and back.  No change thanks for trying though.

Comment: The version mismatch surely is the cause of the problem.  I'd guess you need to either uninstall and re-install the app on the trouble machine instead of letting it update or dig up that old copy of log4net you once used.

Comment: I assume you're deploying with Visual Studio. Try turning off signing your ClickOnce manifest and then editing the file. If you don't turn off signing, you'll have to resign after editing your file. The easiest way to do that is Mage - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be that you have two dependencies to log4net.dll.
On comes directly from your project, which has it referenced, and one is an implicit reference from another library (typically a library compiled for .net 1.1, in my case it happened with Crystal Reports). My guess is that this two references point to different versions.

1. You could try leaving log4net installed on your target machine, and **Exclude** it from Application Files in the ClickOnce project. This way it will NOT be needed by the ClickOnce installation (but it's not clear to me what will happen once installed, when trying to run the application).
2. If it doesn't work or if it fails at run-time, then maybe setting Copy Local and Specific Version to false in the project that references it would do the trick.
   But then log4net in the GAC will be a prerequisite for the application to run, which means you need to install .NET 1.1 (or 2.0/3.5 full). 350MB of prerequisite is quite heavy...
3. Your idea of changing your manifest file after publishing could
   work. To avoid ClickOnce saying the installation is corrupted, you
   need to resign the publication using MAGE (Manifest Editing and
   Generation Tool, normally available from the Start Menu group from
   Visual Studio). I don't know what will happen if your application
   really needs log4net at run-time and cannot find it.

Comment: You are correct, it was a another library that had a reference to log4net in the GAC.  I found it when I was trying to make a MSI install and bypass ClickOnce.  That project showed two references to log4net and I was able to track it down.  However I am still confused why it only was an issue on one computer and not any others?  But it is working now and that is the bottom line I suppose.  thanks a bunch

Comment: Beats me. My guess would be that there was a different version of log4net.dll installed on the machines but I suppose you already checked that.

Comment: Ok I finally think I tracked it down.  It *appears* that the SAP Crystal Reports run time for .NET 4.0 puts a copy of log4net in the GAC.  I am not positive this the issue, but everything I have looked at is pointing at this.  cheers  bob

Comment: I'm not sure, I thought that the CR runtime for .NET 4.0 needs it, but the log4net library is not installed by default by the .NET 4.0 framework, because this version of the framework is not cumulative (it does not include the previous versions of the framework), and log4net is actually a .NET 1.1 (or 2.0, not sure) library. So, if you don't have any of the cumulative versions of .NET (1.1, 2.0 or 3.5), CR can't work, even though it is theoretically for .NET 4.0. Anyway, I'm switching to Reporting Services now :)